# Looping through HTML table with Javascript/jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html-table

I am struggling to figure out how to loop through a table in HTML.

I have a 2D Javascript object that I would like to populate cells with `index i,j` from `myObject[i][j]`. I have a basic html table template but with blank `<td></td>` tags. I have looked at ways to do it in jQuery and Javascript, but to no avail.

Edit: Here's my code:

```
var table = document.getElementById("myTable");
for (var i = 0, row; row = table.rows[i]; i++) {
   for (var j = 0, col; col = row.cells[j]; j++) {
     col = myObject[i][j]
   }  
}
```

My HTML is just a standard table eg.:

```
    <table id="myTable">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th></th>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td></td>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <th></th>
            <td></td>
        </tbody>
      </table>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: show us more code and what you have tried to do

Comment: We can't really help you debug your code without *seeing* your code...

Comment: So you want to fill table from object?

Comment: Yes - exactly. Each index in the object is matched to the corresponding row/col index in the table.

Comment: @Karl Do you want to generate this table or you already have it?

Comment: You can try something like this: https://jsfiddle.net/pt9go1s6/

Answer (score 0):

A jQuery solution could be use [child related selectors](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/child-filter-selectors/) to filter relevant cells.

```js
var ar = [
  ['A', 'B'],
  ['C', 'D']
];
for (var r = 0; r < 2; ++r) {
  for (var c = 0; c < 2; ++c) {
    $('table tr:nth-of-type(' + (r + 1) + ') td:nth-of-type(' + (c + 1) + ')').text(ar[r][c]);
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>.</td>
    <td>.</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>.</td>
    <td>.</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: It is not a good practice to access DOM nodes in loops (for, while...). This slows down you code significantly. jQuery tries to find selected node every loop which can be pretty slow. Also, this jQuery selector is not very readable, especially when you come back to your code after some time.

Comment: You're completely right, and I wouldn't have put this kind of code in a production context. Anyway, the purpose was only to provide some kind of proof of concept.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @bulicmatko

> You can try something like this: jsfiddle.net/pt9go1s6

Comment: I posted this as an answer :)

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

**HTML**:

```
<div id="tableWrap"></div>
```

**JS**:

```
var tableWrap = document.getElementById("tableWrap");

var data = [
    ['First Name', 'Last Name', 'Age'],
    ['Johnny', 'Bravo', '27'],
    ['Bugs', 'Bunny', '35'],
    ['Mickey', 'Mouse', '35'],
];

var table = "<table>";

for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    table += "<tr>";
    for (var j = 0; j < data[i].length; j++) {
        table += "<td>" + data[i][j] + "<td>";
    }

    table += "</tr>";
}

table += "</table>";

tableWrap.innerHTML = table;
```

Here is the [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/pt9go1s6/1/).

Hope it helps ;)